# Plotly express doesnot show image in vscode jupyter

Tags: visual-studio-code, plotly, jupyter

I am trying to us plotly express function `px.imshow()` to display an image in vscode-jupyter but dont get the correct image.

Any ideas how to fix it?

```
from torchvision import datasets 
import os 
import plotly.express as px
os.chdir("books/deep-learning-with-pytorch")

data_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"data")
cifar10 = datasets.CIFAR10(data_path, train = True, download = True)

img_99, lab = cifar10[101]
fig = px.imshow(img_99)
fig.show()
```

Produces this on the cell below

[image]

The Same code in a `.py` file produces this image in the web browser.

[image]

Comment: Does [it](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/#choose-the-colorscale-to-display-a-singlechannel-image) improve if I set `binary_string=True`, as described here?

Comment: try this:`fig = px.imshow(img_99,binary_string=True)`

Comment: Thanks but nope it isn't working